# XSL Getting Rid of Space to the Left

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to Display an Address in Multiple Lines using XSLT. The XML is generated via Frame work that Has some blank spaces to the Left of the 2nd & 3rd lines. So, cant Change XML.

Tried using `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`

Does not Help. Address currently displays as:

```
ABC Company Limited
  No.24, Lines Rd
    Pannmure, USA
```

I do not want to restrict to a length of strings a Line can hold. Needs to Display this as:

```
ABC Company Limited
No.24, Lines Rd 
Pannmure, USA
```

Tried using `normalize-space(data)` - it displays as:

```
ABC Company Limited No.24, Lines Rd Pannmure, USA
```

Don't want this either.

Please try & give me an example hence I am new to XSLT. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Which version of XSLT?

Comment: Show us the minimal input and XSLT necessary to reproduce this problem.

Comment: @Killrawr XSLT does not use DOM as its XML model. But why should you not have access to the whole XML tree all the time and why would you compare XSLT to HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your input is something like this:

```
<text>ABC Company Limited
           No.24, Lines Rd
                    Pannmure, USA</text>
```

So you need to use recursion to pick off the lines combined with normalize-space() to remove the blanks. I just did this for another template, you can adjust to your own liking (like remove the line elements:

```
    <xsl:template match="text">
        <xsl:call-template name="splitlines">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="splitlines">
            <xsl:param name="text"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($text,'&#xa;')">
                    <line>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text,'&#xa;'))"/>
                    </line>
                    <xsl:call-template name="splitlines">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,'&#xa;')"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <line>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/>
                    </line>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
```

Using that input, it would output this:

```
 <line>ABC Company Limited</line><line>No.24, Lines Rd</line><line>Pannmure, USA</line>
```

I will leave it to you to edit out the "line" elements and replace with a linefeed if you like.

Comment: You are assuming no leading/trailing empty lines - which is highly unlikely.

Comment: I didn't assume that as it was not part of the question. You could handle that easy enough with string-length test before outputting the normalized content.